# Visual Studio Code Debug Console does not support \r?

Tags: python-3.x, visual-studio-code

In the Visual Studio Code Debug Console this code:

```
def progressbar_step(t):
    if t % 100:
        print("\r[%-20s] %d%%" % ('='*int(t*0.01), 0.1*t), end='\r', flush=True)
```

has the following output:

```
[                    ] 0%[                    ] 0%[                    ] 0%[                    ] 0%
```

while, when running it in the terminal it works as expected:

```
[                    ] 0%
```

Can anybody tell me, if I did something wrong and this behavior is intended for some reason?

Comment: Try this SO answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61316329/how-to-use-r-escape-sequences-in-vs-code-output-tab