# How to use \r escape sequences in VS-code output tab?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, ansi-escape

The following Python code:

```
print("hello\rworld")
```

... prints `world` under a Python REPL (launched from either Terminal.app (MacOS) or VS-code terminal) and Jupyter Notebook.

However, the VS-code output tab seems to ignore the ANSI-escape sequences:

[image: VS-code output]

Is it possible to override this behavior?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why don't you use `'\n'`?

Comment: I'd say that VS Code did not ignore the `\r` but rather interpreted it as a newline. I suppose it tries to be overly protective of the output and does not overwrite it even when a VT220 would.  Frankly, [a ton of old OSes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline#Representation), including MacOS classic, used `\r` as a newline character.

Comment: @dyz: A classic way to print a live-updating percentage on a terminal is something like `print("%3d%% completed\r'" % percent)`, which would put the cursor at the beginning of _the same_ line, so that the next output would print over the same place on the screen.

Comment: @9000 I know about _that_ use, but my question was to the OP.

Comment: @DYZ yes, as 9000 has guessed, I would like to track the progress of a process without flooding the output. But I have other uses in mind (for text-based games).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try not using the Code Runner extension and use the Python extension to execute your code instead. That way the execution occurs in the terminal where there's a better chance `\r` will do a line feed instead of a newline.

Comment: Yes, I disabled the Code Runner extension and it now works as I want. Thanks a lot!